# Launching links to a chat room - Invitation Program

Tags: c, windows

This is a program you can compile on Windows. The program is an invitation of a chat system for programmers. Once you press enter, you will open the link with your default Internet browser. You can learn more from the program itself.

- 102 lines of code
- 4 377 bytes size of source file
- 192 984 bytes size of binary executable file
- **Do note that the program requires administrative privileges**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define color       "78"
#define title       "E-Chat Invitation By Al3"
#define KEY_ENTER   0x0D
#define KEY_I       0x49

#define echo        "ECHO"

typedef enum OPTIONS {LAUNCH = 10, INFO = 20} option;

int
main
(void)
{
    option main_option;
    HANDLE Handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    FILE* web;

    system("COLOR " color);
    system("TITLE " title);

    menu :
    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 9 | BACKGROUND_RED); // more simplified coloring
    system(echo " Press Enter to launch the e-chat or press i for info\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 143); // combination of 4 bit fg and 4 bit bg
    main_option = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_ENTER)) {   main_option = LAUNCH;   }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_I))     {   main_option = INFO;     }

        if(main_option &&
           !GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_I) &&
           !GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_ENTER))
        {
            break; // Exits the loop only if an option is selected and the key is not bussy
        }
    }

    switch(main_option)
    {
        case LAUNCH:    system("CLS"); printf("Launching..\n");
                        web = fopen("temporal_weblink_echat.url", "w");
                        fputs("[InternetShortcut]\n"
                              "URL=http://e-chat.co/room/34017/\n"
                              "IDList=\n"
                              "HotKey=\n"
                              "IconFile=\n"
                              "IconIndex=0", web);
                        fclose(web);
                        {
                            int
                            execution = ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "temporal_weblink_echat.url", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

                            if(execution <= 32)
                            {
                                char str1[256];
                                char str2[256];

                                sprintf(str1, "Cannot open temporal file. File may have been moved or deleted. Admin rights are required.");
                                sprintf(str2, "Error with error code (%02i)", execution);

                                MessageBox (NULL, str1, str2, MB_OK | 0x00000010L);

                                goto menu;
                            }
                        }
                        if(remove("temporal_weblink_echat.url"))
                        {
                            printf("Could not delete the temporal file, please try again.\n\n");
                            goto menu;
                        }
        break;
        case INFO:      system("CLS");
                        printf("The e-chat is an Online 24/7-running public chat room,\n"
                               "dedicated for programmers, programming in the language C.\n"
                               "Feel free to come at any time if you have any C-related questions.\n"
                               "Note that the e-chat has no sound notification yet,\n"
                               "which means sometimes people can not response at the moment you type something.\n"
                               "No registration is needed,\n"
                               "you can enter as a guest only by passing\n"
                               "the name you want to identify yourself. If you share the link to more people,\n"
                               "the e-chat might become a certain environment for immediate collaboration\n"
                               "when it comes to programming on that particular language.\n\n"
                               "Rules are simple:\n"
                               "1. Do not discuss anything that has nothing to do with C programming.\n"
                               "   - Chat ban follows\n"
                               "2. Do not harass people.\n"
                               "   - Anyone can use an option \"Ignore\" for that purpose.\n"
                               "3. Try using proper and understandable form of communication.\n"
                               "   -Chat kicks as a warning are possible.\n\n"); goto menu;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to say, asking users to run an untrusted binary executable that requires administrative privileges just to open a URL in a web browser sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: I can't believe people don't get the real idea.

Comment: Here's something I noticed by taking a quick look: poor error checking/handling, `system` calls, [`goto`s like that easily makes the code messy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has serious readability issues. And that *is* important. That's the reason we invented C in the first place.

---

This:

```
system(echo " Press Enter to launch the e-chat or press i for info\n");
```

Why did you use a define for `echo`? That looks very bizarre and unnecessary. But why even do that? Forward printing to an external process? Why not just `printf`?

---

"Magic" constants:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 9 | BACKGROUND_RED);
SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 143);
```

What's the 9 and 143 supposed to mean? Isn't there a `#define` for those on `Windows.h`?

Same here:

```
MessageBox (NULL, str1, str2, MB_OK | 0x00000010L);
```

---

Inconsistency with macro naming:

```
#define color       "78"
#define title       "E-Chat Invitation By Al3"
#define KEY_ENTER   0x0D
#define KEY_I       0x49
```

`color` and `title` should follow the `ALL_CAPS` macro/constant convention: `COLOR` and `TITLE`.

---

They way you've indented the `switch(main_option)` is pretty bad. So many levels of indentation for nothing. Rearrange that in a more plausible way:

```
switch (main_option)
{
case LAUNCH:
    ... stuff ...
    break;

case INFO:
    ... stuff ...
    break;

default:
    break;
} // switch (main_option)
```

---

You never check the result of `web = fopen("temporal_weblink_echat.url", "w");`. That's undefined behaviour on the call to `fputs` if `fopen` fails and you use the bad `FILE`.

---

Not mixing `{ }` positioning styles would make your code easier on the eyes of the reader.
Try to be consistent with a single style. Avoid things like this:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(KEY_ENTER)) {   main_option = LAUNCH;   }
```

When the rest of the code is written like:

```
if (x)
{
    do_y();
}
```

---

Heavy use of `goto` can lead to what is called [Spaghetti Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). It would be wise to put some thought into refactoring your program to use more subroutines and avoid `goto`.

Comment: Used goto once like that won't result in SC. I forgot to check these, thanks for reminding me. `while(1)` and `for( ; ; )` are absolute the same except that `while(1)` is more "readable" as you obviously pretty much rely on. I use switch statements on a normal way. No extra styles. Yes i need to keep macro's form. Will make them all with capital letters. Actually using `{` and `}` like that looks much more readable to me. Ahh magic numbers.. They are not even important why do i have to fill my code with more code when it is just.. pointless.

Comment: Also.. Defining a macro for that kind of magic number is not a good idea. That magic number if known.. is good to be modifiable. But its not, unless you have some extra knowledge of how MS deal with console colors.

Comment: @Edenia - I'd say that `while(1)` reads just as strangely as `for(;;)`. I removed that part. It was irrelevant, really. If you use booleans (`stdbool.h`) then `while(true)` would be the most idiomatic form, I guess. But yes, they are all the same on modern compilers.